# Create and use a {NUMBERS array} in jQuery mobile to display content in a list view

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, nsmutablearray

I'm using jQuery mobile and Phonegap to implement an iPhone app and want to implement a list view,  without using hard coded data statistically.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview">
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Not like the above hard code.

I need to create an object like an array with list of numbers (one, two, three, four, five, etc.), and using that numbers array I want to populate in to a list view. How is it possible to create and use an array in jQuery mobile to display content in a list view.

Comment: well, what is it that you don't know how to do? create the array? receive the data? create the list html? refresh the widget?

Comment: yes.. but know create the list view in jQuery mobile but with hard code as shown above

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile + Phone Gap: How to design UI, to display data from data base in to list views dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847490/jquery-mobile-phone-gap-how-to-design-ui-to-display-data-from-data-base-in-t)

Comment: Vijay, please don't post duplicate content on StackOverflow. This just clutters up the homepage. In the [faq], it explains that when you edit your question to improve it, it gets bumped back up to the top of the list; therefore, there is no need to post duplicates. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
var NUMBERS = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
for (var i=0; i < NUMBERS.length; i++) {
    $('#idofmylist').append($('<li/>', {    
            'id': id
        }).append($(NUMBERS[i]))));
}
```

You'll need to give you "ul" an id that you can reference to add the "li"'s using jQuery's append.

Comment: at where in index.html page? or anywhare else

Comment: Well you have to call the JavaScript function when you want to populate the list.